# Read label of aria-live region

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, aria-live

I have a definition list where one of the items can change:

```js
// Update dynamic content
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('dynamic-info').textContent++;
}, 3000);
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Static information</dt>
  <dd>Value 1</dd>
  
  <dt>Static information 2</dt>
  <dd>Value 2</dd>
  
  <dt id="dynamic-info-def">Dynamic number</dt>
  <dd id="dynamic-info" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="dynamic-info-def">1</dd>
</dl>
```

I have put `aria-live` on the content because it needs to be read to a screenreader, which works, but only the number is read. It needs to say "Dynamic number: 2" so the user has context.

I can't put `aria-live` on the `<dl>` because that would be too much content to read. I tried putting a wrapper div around the last `dt/dd` pair, but this is illegal HTML.

I tried using `aria-labelledby` (shown above), but this had no effect (in Chrome with VoiceOver).

How can I make a live region read associated content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An area specified as an ARIA live region will read only its content. It will ignore `aria-labelledby` and `aria-describedby`.

You will need to adjust your function to write the entire text block into the live region.

If you do not want that additional text to be visible, use a [CSS off-screen technique](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/) to hide it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you played with [aria-atomic](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-atomic)?  It will walk up the ancestor tree so it'd have to be set on a parent of the <dd>.  Setting it on the <dt> won't work because it's a sibling.  But you could potentially have have a hidden <span> that's the parent of the <dl> with "dynamic number" as the text.  The <span> wuold have to be hidden by setting its height to 1px instead of really hiding it (visibility) because truly hidden stuff isn't read by a screen reader.  But then if the <span> is only 1px high then that will hide all the children too.  Bummer.

You could also try a brute force method and have a 1px aria-live <span> that you update with "dynamic number 2".  The full text will be read but will not be displayed.  You'd also update your <dd> but it wouldn't have to be aria-live.